# what does "this.x = x < 0? 0 : x; this.y = y < 0? 0 : y;" mean?

Tags: java

I have no idea what does this mean:

```
this.x = x < 0 ? 0 : x;
this.y = y < 0 ? 0 : y;
```

I could not find the meaning of these operators, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: look for ternary operation....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. That [Terinary (or Conditional) Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) in java. A short hand for if and else condition.

The code `this.x = x < 0? 0 : x;` equivalent to

```
if (x<0) {
    this.x = 0
} else{
    this.x =x
}
```

Comment: +1.. Although *Jon Skeet* prefers *Conditional operator* instead of *ternery*. :P

Comment: @TheLostMind Even me prefer after your comment ;)

Comment: @SlodgeMonster The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), however, calls it the *conditional operator*, so I'd say it's the official name for it in Java.

Comment: @SlodgeMonster That is very bad if you referring to Jon Skeet. I don't bother if you are referring to  me :)

Answer (score 2):

Your class has a field named `x`. `this.x` is used to refer to that field unambiguously: you need to do this if there is a local `x` in your scope.

`x < 0 ? 0 : x;` is an idiom that exploits the *ternary operator*. It evaluates to no less than zero.

Answer (score 2):

In this case:

```
this.x = x < 0? 0 : x;
```

This means that the value of **x** is dependent on the condition (the one before the question mark `x < 0`), the value of **x** is the first (the value before the `:` which is `0`) if the condition evaluates to true, else the second value (the value after the `:` which is `x` itself).

Also, The value of **x** is equal to **0** if it is a negative number, other than this case the value is **x** itself.

Answer (score 1):

It means

```
if (x < 0) {
   this.x = 0;
} else {
   this.x = x;
}
```

Which basically means `this.x = Math.max(0,x)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the ternary if operator and basically is equal to:

```
if(x < 0){
    this.x = 0;
else
    this.x = x;
```

same thing for the `y`

and its syntax is `condition ? if_part : else_part;`

Answer (score 1):

it means that:

```
if (x < 0) {
        this.x = 0;
    } else {
        this.x = x;
    }
```

the same for `y;`

Answer (score 1):

The **conditional operator (?:)** returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression.

Syntax: `condition ? first_expression : second_expression;`

```
this.x = x < 0? 0 : x;
this.y = y < 0? 0 : y;
```

**Means if x<0 if true then it will return 0 else return x**
So the value of `x` is depend on the conditions.

Refere [?: Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ty67wk28.aspx) .

Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 1):

It's called Ternary Operator.

```
(condition) ? [if true]
            : [if false]
```

In your case:

```
this.x = x < 0? 0 : x;
this.y = y < 0? 0 : y;
```

- If x is less than 0, assign 0, else assign its value
- If y is less than 0, assign 0, else assign its value

Answer (score 1):

It's the shorthand conditional operator.

The statement 
`int n = x > 0 ? x : 0` 
will set `n` to `x` if `x > 0` returns true. Otherwise, `n` is set to `0`.